# SQL Server "dynamic" Job with SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I've been reading on Jobs and ways to execute an SSIS package dynamically by passing parameters of dates, and I was wondering if my thinking is good or not.

My requirements:

- different employees might need to be able to execute the package with their own dates.
- employees shouldn't be able to alter or run the job it self(they don't even need to know of the job)

I saw that this is possible through [using stored procedures and web applications to build a dynamic job .](https://sunilreddyenugala.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/real-time-job-scheduling/) Though it seems complicated and require a bit more time.

My approach : Using environment variables. [I saw the last answer by the OP in this topic about changing the values of them before execution.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/26f3257f-34f3-486b-ac15-7d0c44b310e4/pass-dynamic-value-to-ssis-package?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

So I was wondering if I can do this (and if it's a good enough solution) :

- Use environment variables
- Build a stored procedure (Not necessarily SP, could be a web app or something) that the employees will be able to use, and sent parameters to.
- The stored procedure will set the environment variables
- The stored procedure will then execute a job, which executes the package(By executing with a job, will the values inside the step be used? or the environment variables?)

Should I go farther with this approach , or should I change it to another one ?

**EDIT:** Thanks to [@PacoDePaco answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46296017/5353753) I've manage to come up with this:

```
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] @package_name=N'CalculateReports.dtsx',
                                           @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT,
                                           @folder_name=N'Packages', 
                                           @project_name=N'HeshbonAmit',
                                           @use32bitruntime=False, 
                                           @reference_id=Null  

Select @execution_id  

DECLARE @var0 sql_variant = N'2017-04-01 00:00:00'  
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id, @object_type=20, @parameter_name=N'startDate', @parameter_value=@var0  
DECLARE @var1 sql_variant = N'2017-07-01 00:00:00'  
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id, @object_type=20, @parameter_name=N'EndDate', @parameter_value=@var1  
DECLARE @var2 sql_variant = N'2017-06-30 00:00:00'  
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id, @object_type=20, @parameter_name=N'shiaruchDate', @parameter_value=@var2  

EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id  
GO
```

But it throws an error:

> Cannot access the package or the package does not exist. Verify that the package exists and that the user has permissions to it.

The project is deployed in SSMS, and is located it this path :

Intergration service catalogs -> SSISDB -> ssis projects -> projects -> HeshbonAmit -> Packages -> CalculateReports.dtsx

My SSIS has 3 package parameters of type string -> startDate, endDate, shiaruchDate .

I have SSIS_ADMIN rule, so why is this failing ?

Comment: Can you please close your last question rather than just asking new ones? I specifically asked you in the last question if users should edit the job and you did not respond, but you have responded here

Comment: The requirement changed. My boss said It's not allowed. I changed my approach , but got stuck in another problem .  @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Sorry for not replying . @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Most forward way would be to [script](https://www.sqlshack.com/execute-deployed-package-ssis-catalog-various-options/) the execution. Sorry I did not mention that earlier

Comment: @PacoDePaco I used the wrong folder name. Anyway, my `set_Execution_parameter_value` throws an error, "The parameter startDate does not exists or you do not have sufficient permissions" .

Comment: If you use the script method from my last comment it will generate the script which includes parameters that you set explicitly in the 'Execute' window prior to scripting. Did you try that?

Comment: Oh I found the problem. The object_type was set to 20 in the example, which is project parameter, and I used package. Changing it to 30 solved me problem. Thank you so much for the help! @PacoDePaco

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck ;]

Comment: Depending on what your package does, you might be able to write a stored procedure to do all of its work, and save yourself all of this hassle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, only one instance of the same job might be running, so one user would have to wait for another user's job to finish. Also, environment variables are not a good way if you think of concurrency - I expect there might be a situation in which two users would like to execute the job with different parameters at roughly the same time. So they both start the procedure, variable gets set to either of the values and the job is executed successfully but how do you know with which value?

I would personally go for executing a package from the stored procedure without putting it into a job. You can supply parameters to each package execution. You said something about the web app, so maybe a managed api would be more suitable way of executing the packages for you. You can find a nice overview of ways to execute packages [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/run-integration-services-ssis-packages).

Comment: Well, in this case there is no problem because this package won't be running twice at the same time. By employees I meant department, which means a boss , and currently her two employees, and they will use this feature once in a quarter . That's why I'm looking for an easy solution. The question is if it's possible (lets say a web app starts a proc, that set up the Env variables, and execute the package)

Comment: Point is that you do not need environment variables to provide parameters to a package, you can just use package parameters. I would say that would be easier because you simply start a package with required parameters using [catalog stored procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-stored-procedures/catalog-create-execution-ssisdb-database)

Comment: Of course you can first configure your package to use environment variables and store values like connection string etc. Then you reference the environment while creating the execution

Comment: Interesting, I have 3 user defined package parameters in my package. So can I use the code in the link you provided , and it will override the parameter value inside my package and run it ? As simple as that?

Comment: Yes, that is what those are for. The parameters you have in your packages after deployment are just default values that you set during the development. I think that if you check the 'Required' option for a parameter in visual studio it will always ask for a new explicit value for this parameter

Comment: I suspected there should be an easy way of execution a package with dynamic parameters, but for some reason, non of my searches had lead me to this solution. Thank you, I'll try it and if it works I'll accept this answer.

Comment: I need a little help, I need to specify the folder the package is being stored inside, but I don't understand which folder.. I tried "packages" but it didn't work. (I'm getting an error of "cannot access the package or the package doesn't exists) . I'll probably have problems with permissions too, but I suspect for now it's due to the folder .

Comment: You need to point to an Integration Services Catalogs folder to which you deployed your SSIS project. You can explore it in Object Explorer in SSMS (Integratioon Services Catalogs node). This is a recommended way. If you do not use project deployment mode but store your packages in the filesystem, you will need to use dtexec command line tool to execute the package.

Comment: I deployed the project already, and it is inside the ISC folder. In the SSMS it's this path -> Intergration service catalogs -> SSISDB -> ssis projects -> projects -> <ProjectName> -> Packages -> <PackageName> . So, the folder is "Packages" ?

Comment: I've edited the question with the code used and the error and all the info needed. can you check it up please?

Answer (score 1):

If you know SSIS pretty well, it'd be an option to use the Environment Variables. Those basically are similar to project-level variables. We typically use them to define connection string settings for a whole SSIS project.

The biggest advantage then is that we can deploy the same solution to different servers (i.e. dev, test, production), and set the desired variables on the individual servers. It also allows you to manually tweak a particular setting in case you need to try and figure out why a single package works on test, but not production; you can simply alter the necessary connection string by editing that particular variable.

For your scenario, though, it sounds over complicated, and perhaps impractical. Of course, it all depends on your technical skills, but having a simple web interface allowing someone to pick a start- and end-date should already do the trick. Once they picked both dates, and click "go", the dates are supplied to the proc as parameters, and you're all ready to go.

If you want to make it a bit more robust, you could consider adding some sort of a queue table where requests are logged on a FIFO basis, with a proc simply scheduled to run on a regular basis to clear the queue. This prevents from the proc being kicked off by several users at the same time, which might end up causing some blocking issues (YMMV, and it might not be a problem at all. However, I like avoiding such stuff in advance if I can).

For extra bonus points, add a loggin table where you register the start-time of the proc being called, the username and parameters supplied, and the end-time. Again, this might not be necessary, but could assist later on with troubleshooting stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I don't need something over complicated, I'm looking for an easy to write solution because this feature will be used only 3 times in the same day in each quarter, by employees that work together(simultaneously calls won't happen) . My question is, is it possible through the Env variables -> An employee supply parameters to a Web app and click go -> An SP is called, defining the Env variables -> The SP then calls a job -> The job calls the Package run.